# In Pygame, how do I clear a blit to replace it with another?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game and on the title screen, I want it to blit the new background (background1) when I press the return key while hovering at coordinates 278,365. How do I make it so that when I press enter at these coordinates, it removes the current background and replace it with the new background1?

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
background1=pygame.image.load(wi1).convert()
cursor=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

x,y =278,365


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                x=420
                y=508
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                x=278
                y=365

            elif event.key == K_RETURN and x==420 and y==508:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.key == K_RETURN and x==278 and y==365:







    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(cursor, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the old background; just blit the new background instead of the old one.

Comment: You can't "clear" blits, you can only blit something else in place.

Comment: You can every loop  clear the whole screen, using [screen.fill()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.fill), with no rect argument. Then draw blit your new scene.

Answer (score 1):

```
# your code
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            # more of your code
            elif event.key == K_RETURN and x==420 and y==508:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.key == K_RETURN and x==278 and y==365:
                #just blit the other image on top of it over it
                screen.blit(background1, 0, 0)
            else:
                #no action performed for other background, set normal background
                screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(cursor, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I didn't have the time to test it but I hope it works :)

Comment: Won't that cover ALL images on the screen?  If you have two images and want to only move one of them, would this solution still work?

Comment: It will work for this question, but if you have more images, you should first blit the background and then all other images. As far as I know the order in which you blit your images matters.